# Acer Aspire ES1 - 111M mouse cursor isn't working

Tags: mouse

I've just finished watching a film and somehow my mouse cursor has disappeared.

How do I get it back and what do you think I could of done for this to have happened?

Answer (score 0):

The immediate workaround: Log off and back on again. (which you've probably already done by now)

The permanent fix: use [VLC](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vlc/) to watch movies.